# iOS - adding a sound on demand in iOS application

Tags: ios, audio, ios7, touch

Ok, here is the situation. I am writing an iOS application, and I have a text scrolling from bottom to top. At a certain point, let's say when the word "EXAMPLE" shows up, I would like to my app automatically play particular sound, let's say "JINGLE".

How do I do it?

Comment: Maybe try to add some code to your question, there is almost nothing to work with here. Are you using UIViews, OpenGL, something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

-(void) playSound {
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"changeTrack" ofType:@"mp3"];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
    //[soundPath release];
}
```

you call in every condition you want